# Cordova doesn't see installed Android SDK

Tags: macos, android-studio, cordova

When I run `cordova requirements` my Mac tells me I don't have any android targets installed, yet Android Studio tells me I have.

[image]

[image]

I have set JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME as below in `.bash_profile`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home

export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/darrensweeney/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
```

Yet when I run `cordova requirements` I see the following:

[image]

Am I missing a step?

I have also tried removing and re-adding the Android platform within Cordova, no difference.

**Update:**

Android Studio was throwing an error `Please select Android SDK` which I fixed by syncing with Gradle.

Now `cordova requirements` shows the following:

[image]

How can I make it see that `android-30` is installed?

Comment: Can you try with ANDROID_SDK_ROOT env variable instead of ANDROID_HOME as mentioned [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/platforms/android/index.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a couple of hours digging, there's a better way to do this:

Install the android-sdk library:

`brew install --cask android-sdk`

This then allows you to use the `sdkmanager` to add any platform:

`sdkmanager "platforms;android-30"`